# laravel HTML class not found

Tags: html, laravel

I am using laravel 5 and I have a problam trying to call to an HTML class.

I add an HTML facade, updated my composer.json file, and I will mention that Form class works fine for me.

I am trying to do the following:

```
Html::entities($content)
```

but I get this error:

> Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Html' not found

Any ideas?

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to properly reference the `Html` alias. Either by importing it at the top:

```
use Html;
```

Or prepending every call with a backslash:

```
\Html::entities($content)
```

---

By the way, for escaping you might just use the `e()` helper, it does exactly the same

```
e($content);
```

Comment: and if I want to do: `str_replace('<', '&gt;', $page->content)` ? how is the right way to do it laravel?

Comment: `e()` or `Html::entities()` or also just `htmlentities($value, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8', false);` (the last is what Laravel actually does when you call those functions)

Comment: for some reason it is not working... I have TinyMCE as a WYSIWYG and it puts the data in a text field in the db, and it prints it as escaped text, not as an HTML.

Comment: Well if you want the raw HTML you don't need to *escape* it at all. Just save it without doing anything else.

Comment: still not working for some reason... looks like laravel still escapes it

Comment: Is it escaped in your database or is it being escaped when you try to echo it?

Comment: it is strange.. in the db it's not escaped, and yet, when I print it noramly it;s escaped. I tried to do this: `$content = str_replace('&lgt', '<', $);` though nothing happened. so I did this:  `$content = str_replace('<', '!!', $);` just to see what happens and it replaces...

Comment: You are probably using `{{ ... }}` aren't you? You should use `{!! ... !!}` to *not* escape output.